# How do I make my script play sounds according to the keys that has been placed?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider:

```
import winsound
import string
import keyboard
listend = keyboard.read_key()
aloop = False
listed = [string.ascii_letters, string.digits]
while True:
    if listend in listed:
            continue
            aloop = True
    elif listend not in listed:
        listend = None
        pass
    elif NameError:
        pass                 # Checks if these are
        listend = None
    elif ValueError:
        pass
        listend = None
    elif listend == None:
        pass
        listend = None
    else:
        pass
while aloop == True:
    for listend in listed:
        winsound


x = listed + '.wav'
meanings = {
    listed: x
}
```

I'm trying to make a keyboardfeedback program that plays a really hard-to-hear noise when one button has been pressed. *listend* asks for inputs here through the keyboard module, and if *listend* = something in listed, it starts the loop *aloop*. I couldn't do *aloop* just yet as I don’t know how to do it. The file names were supposed to be for instance !w.wav! !l.wav! !8.wav! and the portion of the code in the very bottom was used to control it.

#### Updated code

```
import winsound
import string
import keyboard
listend = keyboard.read_key()
aloop = False
listed = str(string.ascii_letters + string.digits)
x = listed + '.wav'
meanings = {
    listend: x
}
while True:
    if listend in listed:
            aloop = True
            continue
    elif listend not in listed:
        listend = ''
        pass
    elif NameError:
        pass                        #checks if these are
        listend = ''
    elif ValueError:
        pass
        listend = ''
    elif listend == '':
        pass
        listend = ''
    else:
        pass
while aloop == True:
    for listend in meanings:
        winsound.PlaySound(listend, winsound.SND_ASYNC)
```

It doesn’t even give any errors by now. There are files named *w.wav*,  *a.wav*, and so on, but none plays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've learned more as the days went on.

```
import winsound
import keyboard
alias = winsound.SND_ASYNC | winsound.SND_FILENAME | winsound.SND_NODEFAULT
while True:
    y = keyboard.read_key()
    x = "pykeyboardfeedback\\" + y + '.wav'
    winsound.PlaySound(x, alias)
```

You have to replace pykeyboardfeedback with the folder your sound files are in.

I don’t know if it is possible, but if you somehow manage to play other sound files in winsound, change the .wav with .mp3. I guess - I don't know.

I'm actually pretty surprised I could finish this in seven lines.

Answer (score 1):

Your first issue is this line:

```
listed = [string.ascii_letters, string.digits]
```

It should actually be:

```
listed = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
```

Otherwise, `if listend in listed:` will always fail, because `listend` will never be equal to `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ` or `0123456789`.